# Hue-Rotate Filter Not Applying to Body Background

Tags: html, css

Like the title says, I can't actually apply hue-rotate to the `body` tag to change the body's background. I tried putting it in the css attributes for the `html` tag to no avail.

An example of my dilemma can be seen at [this codepen](http://jsfiddle.net/4o4w1167/4/).

What's weird is you can add a `background-color` to a `button` and `hue-rotate` it from the same CSS scope, but you can't do the same for the `body` tag. Does anybody know why, and/or has a fix for this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code _within the question itself_. The code within your link will become stale at which point this question fails to be helpful to future readers.

Comment: ... because when you set a background to html or body it is applied to .. html. So to apply the red background to body where filter stands, you need to apply a bckground to html too . http://jsfiddle.net/4o4w1167/5/  http://jsfiddle.net/4o4w1167/6/

Comment: Maybe I didn't totally clarify why I'm seeking this answer - I want the page's entire background color to hue-rotate. Even if I add `hue-rotate` to `html`, it won't rotate the color of the background defined in the `html` tag. However, the example with the buttons shows that you don't need to `hue-rotate` a parent to affect a child. I'm wondering why we can't `hue-rotate` a background color defined in `html`

Answer (score 1):

Use `background : hsl(0%,100%,70%);`
And then apply `filter: hue-rotation();`
It will work.